# How to perform conditional segue operation in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboardsegue

I am trying to perform the conditional segue as per the below code, that if the userid matches the current user id only then the segue is performed but it is not happening as it is required, it performing segue without performing the conditional statement, to call the func toChatView the conditions have to be true

the button is in the tablecell in table View Controller from where the action has to be called

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ItemCell", for: indexPath) as! CommentCell


        cell.itemLikebutton.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.itemLikebutton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(likeaction1(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)


        cell.chatButton.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.chatButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(toChatView(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)




            cell.set(comment: comments[indexPath.row])

        return cell


    }

       @IBAction func toChatView(_ sender: Any) {
        var currentUserId = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
        if currentUserId == userId1 || currentUserId == UserId2{

            performSegue(withIdentifier: "toMessageRoom", sender: self)

        }
        else{
            self.view.makeToast("You are not authorized for this chatroom")

        }


    }
```

now I am getting the error at this inside the prepare func

```
else if (segue.identifier == "toMessageRoom"){

            let chatbutton = sender as! UIButton
            let comment = comments[chatbutton.tag]
            var commentKey1 = comment._documentId
           var commentUserID  =  comment._commentAuthorId
            var messageRoomId = postId + postAuthorId + commentKey1! + commentUserID!
                var vc = segue.destination as! ChatViewController
                vc.MessageRoomPostId = postId
            vc.MessageRoomCommentId = commentKey1!
            vc.messageRoomIdFinal = messageRoomId

                print(postId +  "Check Message Configuration" + commentKey1!)


        }
```

Error is

> Could not cast value of type 'BlogApp2.CommentListViewController' (0x10b31d280) to 'UIButton'

Comment: Well evidently the conditions are true.

Comment: @matt not in every case, after the segue is performed it performs the toast message of condition when not true

Comment: Have you linked the segue to the button in the storyboard (as opposed to the view controller)? If so, then the segue will always fire when the button is tapped.

Comment: @shim yes, i linked the button from tablecell to the destination view controller

Answer (score -1, accepted):

change

```swift
performSegue(withIdentifier: "toMessageRoom", sender: self)
```

to

```swift
performSegue(withIdentifier: "toMessageRoom", sender: sender)
```

Comment: This isn't a complete response; it only addresses a follow-up part of the question, which I already explained in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Link your segue from the source view controller to the destination view controller as opposed to from your button/cell so that it doesn't fire the segue automatically when the tap action occurs.

Linking segues directly to a button (etc) is convenient for quickly firing segues without needing additional code that calls `performSegue` but you cannot use that if you need to trigger the segue conditionally.

Make sure your `IBAction` method is also linked to the appropriate button. Depending on what's in your cell you might want to use the `UITableViewDelegate` method `tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)` instead of an IBAction.

Plus change `self` to `sender` in your `performSegue` call so it sends the button not the view controller to the `prepareForSegue` method.

Comment: @shim I have updated the error on condition being true, data has also to be passed to the destination view controller

Comment: If you send `self` (i.e. your view controller) as the sender in `performSegue` why are you trying to cast it as a button? You could just change `self` to `sender`.